# Using Jpegs as backgrounds

Tags: blender

I am working on a project where I need to add rendered text over a jpeg background image. I have my scene completely set up but when I render all I get is the text, there is no background image. The business name text should be rendering in gold over the background image.

[image]

Comment: This is specifically _in_ Blender? You're not trying to do this at runtime in a game?

Comment: Hi Josh, and no, this is just in blender.

Comment: If you want to mention someone in your comments put an '@' then their name like this: @JoshPetrie. Also, this does not seem to be related to game development and you might get a better answer over at [Blender Stack Excange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's not clear to be how you added the background. Is this through Blender's 'background image' function, or is this simply a textured quad? If it's the first I believe this isn't included in any renders - you would need to do the latter option.

Comment: @Jacob - yes, the background image was added through the normal background function (N key) And no, it isnt showing in the final render.  That's my problem. The company name shows up as desired, now I need to background to be made visible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a blender-question with no relation to game development. So it should be posted on blender stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a [background image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html) in the viewport is only for reference while modeling.

Two ways to get a background image in your render are to use the [import image as planes addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) and align the camera so the plane fills the camera view. Another is using an [alpha over](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html#examples) compositing node to [composite your text over the image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67925/935).

Comment: The first statement is correct, although a simpler approach would be to just create a plane and map a texture to it - no addons required :)

Comment: @JacobPersi You will find the image as plane addon will make it a lot simpler, it sizes the plane to match the aspect ratio of the image, so you don't get any distortion, and quicker than doing it yourself.

Comment: @sambler - Thanks for your suggestions. I'll be applying them as a fix as soon as I get back to my computer. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another post that contains possible solutions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode)

Also, you'll notice that this post is on [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). Questions related specifically to blender might be better asked and receive faster more accurate answers over there.